# VMware Fusion 6.0.4 can't connect from host to guest via ssh

Tags: macos, vmware-fusion

I can't connect from host OS X 10.9.4 to any guest in VMware Fusion, I can't ping guest, nothing. But connection to Internet is working on guest (can ping google.com from it).

And funny part:

1. Restarting VMware Fusion - no help
2. Restarting OS X - helps for about 30 minutes (can connect via ssh, ping guests), then stop
3. Changing subnet in /Library/Preferences/VMware\ Fusion/networking and restarting guest helps for about 30 minutes, then stop

Any ideas? It was working ok like month ago...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I haven't seen this problem and I'm running a few distros and Windows 8 from my 10.9 4 host.  But all of my guests are bridged.

Check what network adaptor your guest OS is using.  The default is NAT'd (aka, "Share with my Mac"). which is not always straightforward.  Try changing this to Bridged (any adaptor that has a green light), make sure your guest picks up a new IP address then ping that from your host.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Switched to Bridged and it's working like a charm!

Comment: Awesome. Glad to hear that helped.